# Lowering z-index causes descendant elements to become unclickable

Tags: html, css

I have a (CSS) stacking question.

The tab-boxes on my development site below have z-index set as -1 so that their border appears behind the tabs above them, so that the active tab's white bottom border covers it. But on all browsers but Opera this makes descendants of the tab-boxes (links, forms, etc.) unclickable. You can see this at:

http://od.philosofiles.com/

Can anyone help? Here's the bare bones of the HTML and CSS, though examining the link above with Firebug would probably be more illuminating:

```
<ul class="odtabs">
  <li id="tab-Authors1" class="first active"><a href="link">Tab</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tab_content-Authors1" class="odtab-content">
  <p><a href="link">Tab Box</a></p>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
  <!--
  .odtabs li {
     float: left;
     background-color: #ddd;
     width: 80px;
     height: 19px;
     list-style-type: none;
  }

  .odtabs li.active {
     background-color: white;
     border-bottom-color: white;
  }

  .odtab-content {
      border: 1px solid #babcbd;
      margin-top: -1px;
      clear: both;
      position: relative;
      top: -1px;
      z-index: -1;
  }
  -->
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed this myself, after a **lot** of experimentation with line-by-line reconstruction. I believe the problem was due to the z-index being negative; however, the only way to make it work with a positive z-index and a higher positive z-index was to set position: relative on the tabs, which required quite a different approach. (Apparently z-index only works on absolute, relative or fixed positioned elements.) Here, for those interested/with similar problems, is the full CSS I used:

```
ul.odtabs {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.odtabs li {
  float: left;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #babcbd;
  width: 80px;
  height: 19px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.odtabs li.active {
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom-color: white;
}

.odtabs a {
  color: #78797c;
  font-size: 0.75em; /* 9px = 12*0.75 */
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

.odtabs .last {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.odtab-content {
  font-size: 0.9166em;
  border: 1px solid #babcbd;
  padding: 0px 1em; /* ie. 12px */
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set z-index to -100.

```
.odtab-content {
border:1px solid #BABCBD;
clear:both;
font-size:0.9166em;
margin-top:-1px;
padding:0 1em;
position:relative;
top:-1px;
z-index:-100;
}
```

Comment: I just have done, and it doesn't help (as you'd expect - whether the z-index is -1 or -100 it'll still be below all other elements, so should be rendered identically)

Comment: hum.. It worked for me wen I changed the value using Firebug in Firefox.

Comment: Does it work for you now I've changed the value in the stylesheet? What Firefox version/OS are you using, and does it work for you in other browsers? I appreciate the help...

Comment: It only works in the latest version of FF. It does not work in IE or Opera. Looks like you have to "play" around with the CSS till you get it working.

Comment: I have the latest version of FF (3.5.3 - on Mac and PC) and it doesn't work, even without any addons. IE works fine; Safari doesn't.